# How to use Android Resources in Application class?

Tags: android

I have a simple question, I can't get my resource drawable in my application class. Is there anyway to do it?

```
public class cApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void sendNotification(String message, Class<?> activityToOpen, int appId) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noticon)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, activityToOpen);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainScreenActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(appId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I have a custom application class to handle some application stuff. I'm trying to delegate all the notification stuff to the Application class but I can't access my resource folder for the small icon.

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noticon)
```

R is not found. How would I resolve this issue or I would implement notification method in a service/activity?

Edit: I'm sorry. I realised that my application didn't rebuild properly, thus R is not found.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the correct answer. Good day to you

Comment: Sorry for the late mark. Was asked to wait for 11 minutes before I could mark your answer, fiddle around with the appcompat library and totally forget about the marking. I've since marked the answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you need clean and build to recreate the R file. Comment the line calling R class and uncomment after it has been generated

Answer (score 0):

R is available in application class Try cleaning your project